# Canon DSLR - Read camera "busy" state

Tags: arduino

I'm going to control my Canon DSLR with an Arduino board.

How can I get current camera "busy" state before firing then next shot so I will keep waiting until it will finish all its jobs?

Comment: What model? I have a T2i (550D) and there is a red indicator for when the SD card is being written. Other than that there is no indication I know of that the camera is still in the processing state.

Perhaps you can use continuous shooting mode with external shutter release.

Comment: Don't know if this applies to your project, but if the aim is to take photos as quickly as possible the continuous shutter mode is worth a look if your camera has that mode.

Comment: the aim is to pause shooting when the camera buffer is full and it is busy with writing to SD + stop shooting (by arduino) in case of any problems (e.g. no more space or battery low)

Comment: There is always this solution: blind timer based on a worst-case, or near worst-case, empirically-determined time.

Answer (score 3):

Canon provides extensive control and status of their cameras via the USB interface, and they provide a software library with a well-documented API to support that. However, this means that any significant remote control needs to be done from a CPU/platform that can be a USB host (and can run the library). It isn't going to be easy from an Arduino.

That said, you might not need that status anyway. The cameras have a significant amount of memory and can take a fairly sizable "burst" of pictures before all of them are written to the SD card. If you establish a minimum time interval between pictures of, say, 500 ms, you should be fine under most circumstances.

Disclosure: One of my current projects is a series of aerial photography "pods" that is based on Canon DSLRs.

Comment: unfortunately RAW images takes much more memory than regular JPG images

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my own solution to this problem (not ideal, but much easier than dealing with canon API and USB-host).

The idea is to connect to the camera`s hot shoe and read a "flash-fire" command from there.

So once camera will get any problems with taking a next photo - you will not receive a "flash-fired" flag after the "take photo" action.. After that you may loop with some timeout in case if camera is just temporary busy with writing or stop any action at all in case if some long timeout still does not allow you to receive a flash-fired flag.

Hope this explanation will help somebody.